# Exponential function definition problem

Tags: solution-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

I have a question about the solution of the equation $$15^{\log_5 x}\cdot x^{\log_5(45x)}=1.$$
After applying logarithms on both sides, we get
$$\log_5 x\log_5 15+\log_5(45x)\log_5x=0.$$
So, we get
$$\log_5x\log_5(15\cdot 45x)=0$$ and $$\log_5x=0\quad \vee\quad \log_5675x=0,$$ so $x=1$ or $x=\dfrac{1}{675}.$
Do we observe $x=1$ as a solution since exponential function $x^a$ is defined for $x>0$ and $x\neq1?$ When we replace $x=1$ in the equation we get true statement, but this definition of a exponential function confuses me.

Comment: "exponential function" is also defined for $x=1$; where do you have this defition from?

Comment: My teacher told such a definition.

Comment: Would you like to check what your teacher has said once again, maybe you find some new insights.